# PhoneGap 3.0 Windows Phone 8 Facebook Plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, windows-phone-8, cordova

does anyone have a working solution to get facebook api/login working on windows phone 8 using the latest phonegap 3.0 version?
The common plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) still doesn't support it, and older versions seem not to be compatible to 3.0.

Thanks.
--Danny

Comment: did you ever get solution to this? Post it here others may also need

Comment: I'm also desperately searching for a solution.